# How to detect undeliverable mails

Tags: django, email

I use [django sendmail](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/) to send mail notifications through gmail.

I allways set `fail_silently` to false. Obviously, this a way to know if I can connect to gmail and if gmail is able to send the message, but not is enough to know if this e mail address is undeliverable.

I want to keep clean email people table. **How can I do to know (by code, not by hand) If an email has been returned as undeliverable.**

Comment: If you want to catch errors why don't you implement logging? [sentry](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) + [raven](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html) are great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the bounce is an asynchronous event. In some cases it might take up to 3 days (or even more) for an undeliverable email to bounce.

In order to detect bounces, your mail server must provide support for it one or another way. Gmail doesn't do this, but you can come up with a heuristic solution using a background process that periodically scans inbox for bounces and parses them using for example imaplib. However, gmail has a sending limit which you will hit sooner or later, so I'm not sure if it's worth investing time in this solution.

Alternatively, you can use an email sending service with bounce tracking capabilities such as [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com)

Comment: Really intesting. I have read docs. Have your tried it? Exists a python / django way to discriminate undeliverable mail, can you link to it? (And yes, I'm already hit by google limits )

Comment: Yeah, I'm using it, but not utilizing the bounce tracking API. The officially recommended way to use Postmark with Django is [python-postmark](https://github.com/themartorana/python-postmark). It provides a mail backend for Django as well as a wrapper for bounce API.

Comment: thanks. I will wait for a more specific answer. If nobody post it this will be a valid answer. Thanks.